# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: pycharm

[Pycharm error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuNBC.png)

There is error when I try pycharm, I couldn't find same problem on google
Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

0xe1 is hex for the value 225. ASCII values are in the range of 0 to 127.

Comment: So, how can I fix it?

Comment: Use a different encoding. If you’re decoding bytes (range 0 - 255), use Latin-1.